# How to get the <input> values from a HTML form using PHP and write values in a text file

Tags: php, html

I have this `html` code with a form (Which is a login-form) which I created using `bootstrap.` And I have this `hi.php` file to get the user entered details (**email** and **password**). But I'm not sure what I have done wrong, because the file (**details.txt**) is empty even after I logged in.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Signin Template for Aviation</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
  }

  .form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
  .form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .form-signin input[type="email"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center">

    <img class="thumbnail img-fluid" src="logo.png">


    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="hi.php">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sri Lankan Air Lines</h2>

      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>

      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>

      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

  </div> <!-- /container -->



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here's my `PHP` :

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("details.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;

?>
```

**Can anyone please tell me where I have done the mistake???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your form input field. You haven't specify name for input fields that's why it is not setting values in $_POST

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Signin Template for Aviation</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
  }

  .form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
  .form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .form-signin input[type="email"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center">

    <img class="thumbnail img-fluid" src="logo.png">


    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="hi.php">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sri Lankan Air Lines</h2>

      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>

      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>

      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>

  </div> <!-- /container -->



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can the name for those fields be anything regardless of the `hi.php`???

Comment: there is nothing to do with hi.php this is name for field ( mostly same as id) you can check in code i have provided in solution (`name="inputEmail"`,`name="inputPassword"`)